# How to get records out of multiple Tables with messy relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, relation

[image]

Hello! I've been working to get records out of this schema, really isn't working out for me.. The relation is so messy

PatPlan table's Ordinal field is an INT (1,2)
1= primary insurance
2= Secondary Insurance

and relation field(the relationship between the patient who has the primary insurance and the patient who has the appointment) works the same way
    1= self
    2= spouse
    3= Child

and the inssub Table Subscriber is a Patient

I need to get basically 3 big categories :

```
1. Appointment's Fields
   -AptDateTime
   -DateTStamp
   -Patient's FirstName
   -Patient's LastName
   -Patient's Gender
   -Patient's Position
   -Patient's EmployerName


2. Guarantor's fields 
   //Same as the Patient's fields (Guarantor is a patient)
   //Must be the guarantor related to the patient who has the appointment
   -Patient's FirstName
   -Patient's LastName
   -Patient's Gender
   -Patient's Position
   -Patient's EmployerName
   -CarrierName
   -EmployerName

3. Primary Insurance (This is the one i can't work it out)
   //Primary insurance is as same as the patient's table
   -Patient's FirstName
   -Patient's LastName
   -Patient's Gender
   -Patient's Position
   -Patient's EmployerName
   -CarrierName
   -EmployerName
```

I will appreciate your help, as I've been working on this 3 days, and I haven't solve it yet.

My current Query:

```
SELECT p.Title, p.FName, p.LName, p.Position, p.Gender,e.EmpName, 

pm.FName AS PMFname, pm.LName AS PMLName, pp.Relationship AS PMPatStatus, 
pme.EmpName AS PMEmpName, i.DateEffective AS PMDateEffective, i.DateTerm AS PMDateTerm, 
c.CarrierName AS PMCarrierName, pme.EmpName AS PMEmpName,

g.FName AS GFName, g.LName AS GLName, pp.Relationship AS GPatStatus, g.Gender AS GGender,ge.EmpName AS GEmpName,

a.AptDateTime, a.AptNum, a.PatNum

FROM patient p LEFT OUTER JOIN Employer e ON p.employerNum = e.employerNum
inner JOIN Appointment a ON a.PatNum = p.PatNum
left JOIN Insplan ip ON ip.EmployerNum = e.employerNum
left JOIN Carrier c ON c.carrierNum = ip.carrierNum 
left JOIN Inssub i ON i.PlanNum = ip.PlanNum 
left JOIN patplan pp ON  pp.InsSubNum = i.InsSubNum AND  pp.PatNum = p.PatNum 
left JOIN Patient pm ON pm.PatNum = i.subscriber 
left JOIN Employer pme ON pme.employerNum = pm.employerNum
left JOIN Patient g ON g.PatNum = p.Guarantor 
LEFT JOIN Employer ge ON ge.employerNum = g.employerNum

WHERE a.DateTStamp > '2012/06/03' AND 
a.AptDateTime != '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What are the queries that you DO have?

Comment: Just updated my current query. Thank You

Comment: What is your question? (What does "get basically" mean? Adding "basically" does not make unclear things clear.) PS When you edit to clarify, Please give a [mcve].